# Journey builder not working properly - Getting 403, 500 errors in marketing cloud AJAX calls

Tags: marketing-cloud, error, journeybuilder, custom

From Yesterday, the journey builder is not working properly and the Marketing cloud AJAX calls are responding 403, 500 errors.

**Webpage :**

[image: Webpage]

**Browser console logs :**

[image]

The **activities** and **entry sources** in the journey builder are not showing up as the AJAX calls returns error.

I thought the issue may be due to the custom activity endpoint so, I updated the endpoints of the custom activity but, the problem still exists.

But, I am sure that before Yesterday, I had created the journeys even though some custom activities endpoint are invalid, It displayed the same error as in the **Webpage** image.

**Here is the response received in the AJAX calls from the browser `Network` tab :**

> Response 403 - {
>   "message": "Authorization token invalid on this endpoint.",
>   "errorcode": 40002,
>   "documentation": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm"
>   }
>
> Response 500 - Error: extensions route returned 403

Anyone please help to fix this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As from the failed routes' URLs this are the standard activities by Salesforce. I got this error once, but it seemed to be a problem at Salesforce and has been fixed about 30 minutes later. Try clearing the cache and cookies, log back in again after some time.

If this doesn't work again in half an hour, reaching out to Salesforce Support should be the best option.

If it happens to be a problem with any custom activities interfering with the standard ones (which I don't think). Just disable them in App Center and try again.

Comment: I removed the custom activities from App Center but, it doesn't fix the issue. I will try clearing the cache and cookies as you said.

Comment: Error still exists after clearing the cache and cookies.

Comment: As I said "I got this error once, but it seemed to be a problem at Salesforce and has been fixed about 30 minutes later.". So clearing the cache on your side won't fix the issue and is just to eliminate possible side effects after this issue has been fixed by salesforce.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I will try to contact salesforce support.